# Calling a method of grand-grandchild from parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component with consuming a context which has a function of the context that needs to be called from the grand-grandparent.

```
const Bar = () => {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <BarContent/>
    </ContextProvider>
  )
}
```

The grand-grandparent is `<Container/>` which is a class component.
Basically the component structure is as follows,

```
<Container> // <= class component
  <InnerContainer>
    <Bar/>
  </InnerContainer>
</Container>
```

I need to call a method on `<BarContent/>` which exposed to that from the context it uses.
I have tried using `React.forwardRef` to call it, but no success at all.

How could I access the method inside the `<BarContent/>` from `<Container/>`

Comment: We can not pass something from child to parent. React only works in the direction of 'Parent to Child' right?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to move your method into another module and call it from there. For example, put it in a module called "utils.js" then import that module into Container.

Alternatively, you could use context. This could be done by changing the scope of your existing context (ie moving ContextProvider so it encloses Container). Or you could create a new context above Container. Remember, there's no limit to the number of context providers you can use.

Comment: The method that needed to call is in the `<BarContent/>` and related to it's data. No point of moving the scope since this is not something used by many. so no luck there it seems.